# Ionic app assinado não instala manualmente

Tags: ionic, app, apk

Galera, eu criei o app release no ionic certinho, criei a chave, assinei o app, passei ele pelo zipaligh e ficou pronto. Problema é que quando eu vou instalar ele manualmente no celular (sem colocar na loja) ele tenta instalar, mas no fim da uma mensagem de que o app não foi instalado. Queria saber se é algum problema com o app ou se somente n instala dessa maneira?

Comment: Eu sempre instalo no meu. Verifique se já tem o app ou algum app instalado com o mesmo package. Você também pode habilitar a instalação de fontes desconhecidas >>> https://www.tecmundo.com.br/como-fazer/25728-android-como-habilitar-a-instalacao-de-fontes-desconhecidas.htm

Answer (score 0):

Se você tinha a versão antiga não assinada no celular, vc deve excluir e então depois disso pode instalar a versão assinada.